# Postgres 10 cluster does not start automatically after I changed the directory data

Tags: postgresql

I changed the postgres data directory following this steps:

```
sudo systemctl stop postgresql

sudo rsync -av /var/lib/postgresql /mnt/volume-nyc1-01

sudo nano /etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf
```

then I edited postgresql.conf:
data_directory = '/mnt/volume-nyc1-01/postgresql/9.5/main'

```
sudo systemctl start postgresql
```

The new directory data is owned by the postgres user.
The problem is that, after starting ubuntu the postgres cluster is down.
I run the command `pg_lsclusters` and got the answer:

```
10  main    5432 down   <unknown> /mnt/volume-nyc1-01 /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.log
```

And after run `sudo systemctl start postgresql@10-main` the cluster starts and postgres works ok.
So what can I do to fix this and the clusters starts normally after Ubuntu starts?

Comment: what does systemctl status postgresql show?

Answer (score 0):

You're editing the PostgreSQL version 9.5 configuration file, as indicated by the directory name.  However, the cluster you actually have and are starting is PostgreSQL 10, and probably has a configuration file in a different location.  Straighten out the agreement between configuration files, PostgreSQL versions, and systemd unit files, and the cluster should start up automatically.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. The correct path of configuration file is /etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf. I just fixed the question. thanks.